# c how we can access pointer to structure without using (->) or (*)

Tags: c

as we study the normal way to access members of a structure using pointers:
1- using Using arrow (->) operator , pointerName -> member .
2- Using indirection (*),   (*pointerName).member.
in flowing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
        static struct 
        {
            int x,y[3];
        } a[3] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}, *p=&a[-1];
        
        int z;
        z= *((int*) (++p+1)-1);
        printf("z: %d \n", z);
        
        static struct 
        {
            int m,n[3];
        } b[3] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}, *t=b+3;
        
        int zz;
        zz= ((int*) (t-2))[-1];
        printf("zz: %d \n", zz);

            
    return 0;
}
```

how :

```
    z= *((int*) (++p+1)-1)
```

gives 4.
the normal ways to get 4 are :

```
p->y[2]
```

or

```
(*p).y[2]
```

also same confusing with zz

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Simply delete the code. It's horrible and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: The source you show has nothing to do with the title of your question. Please clarify what you want to know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then revise your question to something it is possible for the community to answer.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of your code isn't defined by the C standard. In other words - your code has undefined behavior.

In this part:

```
*p=&a[-1]
```

`p` is initialized as a pointer to `a[-1]`. In other words, something like a pointer "to the element before the first element of `a`". The behavior of that is undefined by the standard.

Quote (from draft n1570):

> If both the pointer
> operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
> element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the
> behavior is undefined.**

So from here we can't use the C standard to tell what the code is doing - we can't know for sure.

We can guess but it's only a guess .. no guarantee...

So this:

```
z= *((int*) (++p+1)-1)
```

can be broken into smaller parts

```
++p  // As p points to a[-1]  (which is undefine as mention above)
     // this may produce a pointer to a[0]
```

then

```
++p + 1  // may produce a pointer to a[1]
```

then

```
(int*) (++p+1)  // may produce a pointer to first int in a[1]
```

then

```
(int*) (++p+1)-1  // may produce a pointer to an int just before the
                  // first int in a[1]
```

then

```
*((int*) (++p+1)-1)  // may read the int just before the
                     // first int in a[1]
```

and on your system it's the last int of `a[0]` which has the value 4.

But... just to repeat... This is pure guessing - **the code has undefined behavior so anything may happen**

And the `zz` case ...

First `t` is initialized to point one past the last element of `b`. That's legal. Then `(t-2)` becomes a pointer to `b[1]` (fine) and then `((int*) (t-2))` becomes an int-pointer to the first int of `b[1]` (fine) but when you dereference it using `[-1]` you again have undefined behavior.

**Conclusion:** As I wrote in a comment - Simply delete the code. It's horrible and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your clear explanation. 
This code is the combination from two questions in a mid-term examination of a Chinese university. the request is find the value of z and zz.

Comment: @alzeenahtrad Well, unless the question states a specific platform and compiler/linker etc. the answer to the question is: Nobody tell the values of `z` and `zz`